# Python property getter and setter decorator not callable

Tags: python

I'm doing something similar to the following

```
class Parrot(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__voltage = 100000

    @property
    def voltage(self):
        """Get the current voltage."""
        return self.__voltage
```

However it sees the voltage property as an int so when I call like so

```
p = Parrot()
print(p.voltage())
```

I get

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

I've tried with one and two underscored to mangle the voltage property name.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The whole point of the getter is that it returns the value without being called.  `p.voltage` returns the integer object, so running `p.voltage()` is equivalent to `100()` or something.

There can still be cases where you want to call the value of a property, like if the value is itself a function.  But you don't need it here.

Comment: Now how would I do that with a setter?
Like `code`p.voltage(50)`code`?

Comment: `p.voltage = 50` - the point of Python properties is to support attributes that use the same syntax as simple attributes but can have arbitrary code that gets executed when they're accessed or set.

Comment: You'd use the `voltage.setter` decorator on another method defined in the class after the getter that is named `voltage` and expects `self` and a value argument.

Comment: My new favorite feature of python. Thanks!

Comment: Properties are great, because they let you skip writing getters and setters in the first place.  You can (and should) just use simple attributes rather than do Java-style boilerplate getters and setters, because if you later do find a need for something simple attributes don't support you can refactor into a property without changing any of the calling code.